# Exact same MYSQL Query, returns two different results consistently

Tags: python, mysql, amazon-web-services

Error can be seen in the image below. Effectively running the exact same sql query, will return two different responses [here](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/5752769/49052409-b3a55200-f1b9-11e8-8672-a3c307237171.png).

```
mysql> select * from BTC_USDT_binance where id >= 56057162 and id < 56057791 and bidAsk = 1 order by id asc limit 2000;
Empty set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from BTC_USDT_binance where id >= 56057162 and id <     56057791 and bidAsk = 1 order by id asc limit 2000;
+----------+------------------------+---------+----------+--------+-------+
| id       | date                   | price   | volume   | bidAsk | reset |
+----------+------------------------+---------+----------+--------+-------+
| 56057163 | 2018-11-27 00:49:46.63 | 3848.26 | 0.201554 |       |           |
| 56057164 | 2018-11-27 00:49:46.63 | 3835.31 |        0 |       |       |
| 56057168 | 2018-11-27 00:49:47.64 | 3848.27 |      2.1 |       |       |
| 56057175 | 2018-11-27 00:49:48.64 |  3848.3 | 0.086733 |       |       |
| 56057176 | 2018-11-27 00:49:48.64 | 3848.27 |        0 |       |       |
| 56057177 | 2018-11-27 00:49:48.64 | 3848.31 | 0.085672 |       |       |
```

#### Second Image to showcase it:

```
mysql> select COUNT(*) from BTC_USDT_binance where id >= '56057162' and id < '56057791' and bidAsk = 0;
+----------+
| COUNT(*) |
+----------+
|      316 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select COUNT(*) from BTC_USDT_binance where id >= '56057162' and id < '56057791' and bidAsk = 0;
+----------+
| COUNT(*) |
+----------+
|        1 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select COUNT(*) from BTC_USDT_binance where id >= '56057162' and id < '56057791' and bidAsk = 0;
+----------+
| COUNT(*) |
+----------+
|      316 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select COUNT(*) from BTC_USDT_binance where id >= '56057162' and id < '56057791' and bidAsk = 0;
+----------+
| COUNT(*) |
+----------+
|        1 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> select COUNT(*) from BTC_USDT_binance where id >= '56057162' and id < '56057791' and bidAsk = 0;
+----------+
| COUNT(*) |
+----------+
|      316 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

### Notes/Observations on this:

I have turned off other connections, am not storing to the table at all. It happens consistently every other - meaning that if I run it once, it will return one result (typically a large query/result of a couple thousand responses), and if I query it again, it will return the other (a single record).

Note this is not related to space constraints on the primary key or anything related to this. The database schema is as follows [here](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/5752769/49052473-0d0d8100-f1ba-11e8-9545-4655feacb1a6.png).

```
mysql> describe BTC_USDT_binance;
+--------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field  | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id     | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| date   | timestamp(2)        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| price  | float               | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| volume | float               | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| bidAsk | bit(1)              | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| reset  | bit(1)              | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+--------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

### Hacks Around

If you limit the number of records drawn (i.e. only pull 100 records at once), the problem goes away. This happens until around 1,000 records. This can be easily seen/reproduced by running (varying the value of N):

`select * from BTC_USDT_binance where id >= 56057162 and id < 56057791 and bidAsk = 1 order by id asc limit N;`

If you instead only use a single-sided greater than, and use a limit, the problem goes away as well. This is seen in:

`select * from BTC_USDT_binance where id >= 56057162 and bidAsk = 1 order by id asc limit 500;`

### Other Details and Notes

This is on an amazon RDS of mysql. 
Engine: MySQL 5.6.37
DB instance class: db.t2.medium

### Help

If you direct message me or post below, I can provide access to the database for you to try and play around with the datasets.

Comment: `I can provide access to the database for you` ... please _don't_ give your AWS credentials to anyone.

Comment: You are absolutely correct. I have a public facing version of this database that runs through a proxy.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can see the same query returning two different result sets is if, somehow, the underlying data is being changed.  The obvious cause might be if data is being added/removed in between when you run the same query twice.

However, in the case of AWS, there is another explanation.  If your database instance is logically replicated across RDS, then it might be possible that the first query hits the database before newly added/removed data has been replicated across RDS.  That is, your query could actually be executing against a slightly out of date database.

Comment: Great points on this. There is no incoming data - I have stopped all other connections, and if this were the case then repeatedly doing it would yield different results, but for me it literally oscillates every query. On the AWS point, this actually is my leading theory as well. Do you advice on how to test this? Another note on this is that this bug only occurs at the end of the database - that means that if I pull a query that does not go to the end of the database it is consistent.

Comment: This is as much as I can really say.  Note that there is no "end" or "start" to the database.  But given that you are using `ORDER BY id` with `LIMIT`, my guess is that one table might be missing newer data.

Comment: Also, are you using a free tier?  I seem to recall that free tier might have some delay in replication.

Comment: Nope, it is not free tier - specifically we have the medium versus micro instance, and 2k GiB of storage. However, I don't exactly know how to check for 'free tier' - my understanding is it is just the default settings. It does not have Multi-AZ deployment. By the way, thank you a million you are incredibly kind.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem... with a limit of 1000 works fine... I suspect the problem is on the mariadb driver, im using the latest https://github.com/mariadb-corporation/mariadb-connector-c
In my case the underline db is memsql. Using their web interface I have no problems, for now im limiting 1000 records

Comment: Why should Connector/C manipulate result sets received from server?

Comment: when you access via command line or application, the connector that makes the connection and brings the results, however the problem could be with the database itself. My guess is the connector, but I could be wrong.

Comment: One think I noticed, in my case my application is in C++ and I added

**    mysql_options(_mysql, MYSQL_OPT_READ_TIMEOUT, (const char *)&connect_timeout);**

increasing the connect_timeout made the problem go away so far... I'm still testing this out